# my icecast stream stops playing in FF 41. worked with 38, 39,40. what should I do?

Tags: firefox, icecast

I'm [Nimble Streamer](https://wmspanel.com/nimble) developer responsible for icecast support. I've checked my icecast implementation with FF regularly and everything was fine till 41 release. Please take a look at the following example http://104.131.143.22/ff41issue/stream/icecast.audio it's mp3 icecast stream. Stream plays fine for 38,39, 40.0.3 releases but start reproducing strange noises(drop-outs and jitter/stuttering) on 41 version.

Comment: Have you tried if this happens with one of the officially supported stream formats of Icecast? Ogg/vorbis, Opus, WebM, etc.

Comment: Nimble streamer doesn't support Opus/Ogg/Vorbis as least for now but I was sure mp3 is supported as it plays. Moreover many icecast stream from Icecast server plays fine. Streams from my server stops playing with latest release and this is why I think it's new issue in firefox relating to audio buffer processing or something like that. Other browsers and mobile devices plays provided stream without any issues

Comment: I've tried other Icecast mp3 streams and they all play without any problems with Firefox 41. I think the problem may be in Icecast configuration or MP3 encoder that you are using. Can you post additional info - Icecast version and it's config file, and mp3 encoder (LAME or whatever)?

Comment: I checked several Icecast streams from Icecast server and they plays but sometime I see same effects in case of bad network conditions. Icecast server plays more stable than Nimble but again before 41 version Firefox played fine even icecast streams produced by Nimble streamer. The problem not in icecast configuration/codec as previous FF versions works fine with the stream. I downloaded all version starting from 38 and checked exactly the same stream. Can I ask somebody from FF dev team to check why this stream stops playing with latest FF? Is it right place to ask questions to dev team ?